# Prevent MS Word Linked Tables from using Sharepoint Link

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

When I shift+F9 on a table in a word document I've linked to a local excel document, it seems to prefer to use the sharepoint web address rather a local or relative address.  How do I force MS word to link using a local file path rather than the sharepoint web address?

Comment: Have you tried putting the Excel file in the same folder as the Word document?

Comment: The excel file IS in the same folder.  The problem stems from the fact that the folder is a onedrive\sharepoint folder.